# What are the pros and cons of historial and Gaussian approaches to VaR?

Tags: risk, value-at-risk

What is the difference between historical and Gaussian method of VaR estimation?

I know how they are calculated, but what are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: Have you tried searching for this? There is a lot of info out there.

Comment: I have, but didn't find anything really relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Historical Simulation**

*Pros:*

- Easy to calculate
- Doesn't make assumptions about distribution of returns (uses empirical distribution)
- Can add some enhancements onto it such as giving a higher weighting to more recent returns (prevents ghosting mentioned below) or a weighting by volatility where more volatile returns get a higher weight.

*Cons*:

- Assumes the past will repeat itself, doesn't consider events that it has not seen before
- If you use the most basic historical simulation approach, as your historical window shifts, large losses or returns at the edge of the window will no longer be in your data-set and can cause a significant jump in the Var (this is called ghosting) which in very undesirable

**Guassian/Parametric/Delta Normal/Variance-Covariance (has many names)**

*Pros*:

- Relatively easy to calculate (more work than historical, but less compared to monte carlo)

*Cons*:

- Assumes returns are normally distributed, which is often incorrect
- Assumes delta sensitivity accounts for all the risk
- Very inaccurate for non-linear positions like options (because of above point re delta)
- Need to compute an NxN covariance matrix for the portfolio.

Comment: which one is used the most? monte carlo?

Comment: No idea sorry. If I had to make an educated guess, historical as it is the least data and process intensive.

Comment: Thanks anyway! Maybe some praticioner will input something

Comment: But guys: in usual Monte Carlo approaches: what do you do? Estimate a covariance from historical data and sample Gaussians. There are more sophisticated approaches but in the basic case: what is the difference?

Comment: Monte Carlo simulation is quite different. Here are a couple of posts on the topic: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/calculating-var-with-monte-carlo-simulation and http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/12592/is-there-a-step-by-step-guide-for-calculating-portfolio-var-using-monte-carlo-si