# How to calculate the VaR of a portfolio containing Stocks and ETFs?

Tags: value-at-risk

I would like to use the approach outlined [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/12592/is-there-a-step-by-step-guide-for-calculating-portfolio-var-using-monte-carlo-si) to calculate portfolio VaR.

However in my case the portfolio also contains ETFs (where I don't necessarily know the fund's total composition. I usually have the top 10). Can I still apply the Monte-Carlo method? If yes how should I modelize the ETF?

Comment: You can still use Monte Carlo if you think that this is the best way to capture the risk of stock and stock-like instruments. I would be careful on the assumptions of the distribution however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to model the constituents of the ETF individually. You can consider it as a single asset and model it like any other stock in the portfolio. for example If you would have an index future, then I would also not model the constituents but just model the future as a single instrument.